# angular 9 dependency injection error. " The class cannot be created via dependency injection, as it does not have an Angular decorator

Tags: angular

The same code worked for me in angular 8 but now it's giving me this error. 
"The class 'BaseService' cannot be created via dependency injection, as it does not have an Angular decorator. This will result in an error at runtime.

```
Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'BaseService', or configure a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory')."
```

I'm only trying to achieve simple inheritence here.

1) BaseService.ts (parent class)

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export class BaseService {
    url
    constructor(postfixUrl) {
        this.url = environment.backendUrl + postfixUrl
    }

    setUpHeaders() {
       return {
           headers: new HttpHeaders({
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           })
       }
} 
}
```

2) AuthService.ts (child class)

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { BaseService } from './base.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })

export class AuthService extends BaseService {
    url
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        super('auth')
    }
    register(user) {
        return this.http.post(this.url, user, this.setUpHeaders())
    }
}
```

3) auth.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule


  ],
  providers: [AuthService, BaseService]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AlSv.png)

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the error message?

Comment: By the way I have tried putting @Injectable() in base class. it gives me the same error.

Comment: @KurtHamilton yes I did

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using both `@Injectable` and adding the service to the module providers?

Comment: @KurtHamilton why cant I do that? sorry for my lack of knowledge. Lol, Thanks it works now

Comment: Added my answer. BaseService shouldn't be added as a provider, and you would generally use only one of `@Injectable` or `providers` - not both

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use a service for a single module then you do not need to use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`.

**Two steps:**

1. `@Injectable()` add in your service.
2. `providers: [ BaseService ]` add in your module inner `NgModule`.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `BaseService` to the module providers. `BaseService` accepts the parameter `postfixUrl` in its constructor.

You should remove at least the `BaseService` from the providers, since Angular won't know how to resolve the parameters.

Adding a service to the module providers means that an instance of that service will be shared within that module. Adding `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` means it will be shared within the whole app.

You 2 competing methods of registering services for dependency injection, and registering `BaseService` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was facing similar issue while upgrading from angular v8 to v9 and my import are with path-mapping

```
import { Injectable } from '../../../../node_modules/@angular/core';
```

Resolved the error by removing the path-mapping

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```